# How do know if I can SSH in servers?

Tags: linux, ssh, ip, ping, ssh-tunnel

I have over 200 servers, but is hard to keep tracking all of them by some documents, after a while it gets outdated, so to refresh this document, I have to know which servers I can login via `SSH`.
I already create a script which gonna ping through a range of IP address, with this list now I would like to know if I can SSH into them. I was thinking in a combination of `sshpass` and `ssh` inside a loop, but wonder if that's the best solution.

Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: This is why people use configuration management tools. Check puppet, chef, cfengine or any other. Use `nmap -p 22 --open -sV 10.0.0.0/24` if in a hurry (replace with an actual subnet).

Comment: I'm starting to use chef in our servers, but not all machines are on it right now, I'm putting them slowly, to avoid any complications.
I didn't know this `nmap` command, I will look into it.

Comment: What are these servers used for?  I.e. what is the "master list" that must always get updated regardless of the state of other documents?  DNS?  `/etc/ethers`?  dhcpd.conf?  Or are all hosts simply on the same subnet?

Comment: @ghoti, they're in different datacenters, so they don't have the same subnet. The document that I'm talking about it is a datasheet of excel, where I have all my server there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dawud's suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/507984/how-do-know-if-i-can-ssh-in-servers#comment571824_507984) is good, you can also pass a list of servers to `ssh-keyscan` to scan them and log the server's public key.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is asking how to compile a list of servers running an `sshd` (in which case your answer works), or whether he's asking how to compile a list of servers that *he personally can log in to*, in which case it won't.

Comment: Me either. Not My Problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use some monitoring program like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) for this instead of writing your own scripts. It will alert you if some server goes down.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is asking how to monitor, but simply if they have SSH access (regardless of the state of the machine).